# Where are SQL Linked Server view definitions?

Tags: sql, db2, ssms, linked-server

I've migrated and moved linked servers before, but never had to modify one, so this issue is mostly foreign to me.

Here's the situation (with table names obscured but consistent):

SQL Linked Server `SQLXYZ1`-> Catalog `XYZ` -> View `HRIS.ZZ_VIEWNAME`

This "view" definition maps to a DB2 table on the AS/400 called `DB2.TABLENAME`.

Here's the issue: I added a new column to the DB2 table `DB2.TABLENAME`, but when it comes through the linked server (via this view), the new column is coming through wrong because the linked server side of the view definition doesn't know about it.

If I right-click and generate a Select statement from view `HRIS.ZZ_VIEWNAME` on the SQL linked server side, the columns that come back is the OLD definition of the table that no longer matches `DB2.TABLENAME`. There's also the fact that the linked server side of things has a prefix of "ZZ_" on the table name, which someone had to type in somewhere, but I can't figure out where... So if `ZZ_VIEWNAME` is a "view" that the linked server sees, how can I find out where this view is? Is it a SQL view or DB2 view?

My question is: Where is the "definition" of the view that the SQL linked server sees?

I've asked our top SQL manager here, who insisted it's not in SQL, but must exist on the AS/400.

I've asked our top AS/400 manager here, who insisted that such a thing is not done on the AS/400/DB2 and must exist on the SQL side.

So essentially, nobody knows where this definition is.

As someone who doesn't know linked servers and the experts here can't agree, where is the definition of external view that a SQL linked server sees?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say _"table" definition maps to a DB2 table_? How is this "mapping" done? What's the DDL statement for `HRIS.ZZ_TABLENAME`? Do you mean by chance that `HRIS.ZZ_TABLENAME` is in fact a view that selects from `SQLXYZ1. DB2.TABLENAME`?

Comment: @mustaccio Sorry I was looking in the wrong place - you are correct, it's a view, but still one that's not named after any view in the source system and one I can't do a "Script View as -> CREATE VIEW" to see the source or where it's pointing. The nodes in the hierarchy int he side panel go "Linked Servers"->[linked server name]->Catalogs->[catalog name]->Views->HRIS.ZZ_VIEWNAME, however, I can't reconcile where that view is, anywhere, only what table it pulls data from

Comment: It looks like the view is on the DB2 side. Try something like `select view_definition from qsys2.sysviews where table_name = 'ZZ_VIEWNAME'`. If it's there you'll need to re-create the view (or ask someone to do so) for it to pick up the new column from the underlying table.

Comment: @mustaccio Great idea - unfortunately, it was just a lack of knowledge here regarding the architecture - turns out there's a "man in the middle" linked server ([SQL]->[linked server]->[linked server on a previously unknown SQL server]->[AS/400]). So both my coworkers were right about denying ownership, because it was some other dev's in-between SQL server I didn't know about. Sorry! Good tip on finding tables by name from the DB2 side though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was another dev's intermediary linked server in the middle, so my question was invalid from the very start.

Someone overarchitected a disaster of a database which is apparently going:

Application -> SQL server view -> Linked Server -> SQL server view -> Synonym in an incorrect database -> Linked Server -> DB2 table